# AJAX CakePHP Pagination save data from different pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, pagination

I have a view that lists items, and it's a long list so I use Paginator to limit items to 10-to-a-view.

Each item has a checkbox and each checkbox stores the "item ID" of corresponding item. Each page also have a submit button, Now what I want to implement is:

on click of submit button, all selected items's id get save into database but selected items from older pages get lost when next page has been selected. Please help me out how can I implement it in cakephp

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I would use cookies or session: when you click specific item it's ID is saved to a cookie/session and then submit button action reads data from cookie/session and saves it to the database...

Comment: i just reread the question and my answer was different